# Minecraft in-game text color

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am head-developer on this server, and I am creating portals to other parts of the server. I have added floating text using the Holograpic Display plugin. On another server I saw text floating, but the color of the text was constantly changing. I understand how to change color text: &1, &2, &n, ect. Do I need another plugin or am I just missing another one of &examples?

Comment: I don't know, but is §1 for Blue, not &1 for Blue?

Comment: Its & for the computer I use

Comment: @NukesPlus Most plugins use & instead of the vanilla § as it is easier to type for a normal user.

Comment: It's probably this plugin: http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/coloredtexts OP, please confirm or deny

Comment: @angussidney It isn't even possible to type the § in vanilla Minecraft in the chat anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Its problably a plugin that they used, maybe ask the server admins or the owner for the plugin if its not custom made, as I know to my knowledge, there is no & command for floating text.

Comment: I have used this plugin, but I don't have access to my server right now. I will tell you the name when I am able to access it again.